# Spring boot app does not serve static resources after packaging into jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a application that work perfectly fine when started via IDE or command line: `mvn spring-boot:run`. But when I package it into jar, I cannot access static resources(404 not found). I did not want to store static files in resource fouler so I don`t have to reload the server each time I need to change static file. So I used this plugin in my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I can see that files are being copied in two the directory "static".
This is my configuration of resource handler:

```java
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
  }
```

Controllers RequestMappings are working fine, problems are only with the static resources.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's usual with Boot to simply put the resources in a directory `static` or `public` in the resources directory and let Boot's default MVC configuration handle registration. You could cut all of this code.

Comment: is the plugin executed? Can you see it in the output log? Did you define it in `build/plugins` or `build/pluginManagement/plugins`?

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo , i define it in build/plugins, and yeah it works, i can open the jar with winRar and see the static folder in there with all files from webapp folder

Comment: @chrylis yes, but will i still be able to edit my files without a need to restart the server?

Comment: That depends on how you launch. I launch from Eclipse with workspace resolution and don't have any problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should supply multiple resource locations for resolving:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/", "classpath:/static/");
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this is really useful, i did not even knew, that it was possible to provide multiple locations

Answer (score 0):

For me, static resources stop serving up when I add the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class. Without it, it works fine.