# Access javascript files present inside JAR in parent springboot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have to provide static .js files through a JAR project.
For this I created a JAR(using MAVEN) which looks like:

```
parent
|--com
|--META-INF
|--webapp
   |--resources
      |--js
         |--myjs.js
```

Now, I added this JAR to my parent spring-boot project and in one of the `JSP`s added

```
<script src="resources/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

This gives me a 404 error.

My conclusion: Either the boot project does not merge `webapp` folders from JARs into its own `webapp` or I am accessing the file incorrectly.

These questions did not help(cannot change `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and java code is strictly not allowed ):

[SpringBoot - accessing a file inside resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815290/springboot-accessing-a-file-inside-resources-folder) 
[Serve static resources within jar files by Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154195/serve-static-resources-within-jar-files-by-spring-boot)

Usually, such things are handled using [overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) but that would be and overkill for a simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp folder is secured folder.You cannot access files directly inside it.
You need to permit all your incoming requests of js and other static files as following:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```